# how to right justify a string or number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need a column of numbers to be right justified.
In 'C':   printf("\n %10d   %10s"...)

How is this done in JavaScript?

Comment: There are many implementations of sprintf in javascript. For example http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-sprintf.html or http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are printing the numbers in a web page using JavaScript, you'll want to use the CSS text-align property.

For example, if you're writing out the column of numbers in a DOM element `<div id='myNumbers'>`, you could write

```
document.getElementById('myNumbers').style.textAlign = 'right';
```